# Android: textView doesn't show cursor

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView which is configured as an EditText. But the problem is that the cursor doesn't appear when i'm pressing keys (text is written correctly).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the first thing I'd try is [setCursorVisible](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCursorVisible%28boolean%29)(true)

Also you say you have a TextView which is configured as an EditText.  That's a bit confusing to me.  Did you define it in your layout XML as `<EditText>` or create a new EditText object via `new EditText(context)`?  Or did you define it as a `<TextView>` with `android:editable="true"`?  Your wording sounds almost like you did the later, but I'm not sure that's going to work as well as the former.

For future reference, posting the code that's not working as part of your question really helps people pinpoint your problem and provide you the correct answer.

Comment: i have the second choice because i need a textview that looks like as edittext. but i found the solution:

modify style of a edittext in order to be similar to a textview

Comment: so, did setCursorVisible(true) fix the original problem?